# Editing all columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, update

I have a db table with more than 200 rows (table name: `ports`).

There is this column (`port name`). The data in the column is like: `aaa 1/15`.

I want to edit all the data in this and turn the `aaa 1/15` to `1/15`.

Of course the column value differs. One ends with `1/15` The other with `2/18`.

So the point is, I want to get rid of all the `aaa` in that column for all rows. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: *I want to get rid of all the `aaa` in that column for all rows* Does all column values have the same prefix `'aaa '`? if not - what is criteria of a border between part to be removed and part to be stored? space? last space? something else?

Comment: On the same line of thinking, are you able to safely say that exactly the last 4 characters of the column are the only ones you want to keep?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It goes like this "aaa - 1/15". And the last part i want to get is either 3 or 4 characters. Ex: 1/2 or 1/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> last part i want to get is **either 3 or 4 characters**. Ex: `'1/2'` or `'1/12'`

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [ColumnName] = LTRIM(RIGHT([ColumnName], 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options, depending on the state of your data. If the prefix is ***always*** 'aaa', then do this:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [ColumnName] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE([ColumnName], 'aaa', '')))
```

If the prefix changes, but it is always the last 4 characters you want to retain, then do this:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [ColumnName] = SUBSTRING([ColumnName], LEN([ColumnName])-4, 5)
```

If the prefix and length varies, but is always separated by a space (and this is the only space in the field) you can do this:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET [ColumnName] = SUBSTRING([ColumnName], CHARINDEX(' ', [ColumnName]), LEN([ColumnName])-CHARINDEX(' ', [ColumnName])+1)
```